# how to create a removal button that depends on his parent and make a function remove() by jquery on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I need to search by whether it is one query or more. I'm not strong in Javascript or Jquery, however, the function does very well whether for (plus button) in one or more query and for (removal button) for one query only bt when it created if there are more than one search field sometimes be created and sometimes not created. I don't really know what is going on but all I notice that when I click on (plus button) which has the removal button it can create a new removal button and if I click the plus button in the parent that hasn't button removal the removal button doesn't create.

there are my code and screenshot to see the error but please note that I do for-loop in HTML elements into form to retrieve the number of requests that exists in the query to create the same number of search fields therefore, I create the button that adds and remove that search except for the first field.

[correct search added for removal btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcX73.png)
[wrong search added for removal btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiagN.png)

search.html

```
<div class="search-field">
                <h2 class="show"></h2>
                {% if query_length|length < 2 %}
                <form method="get" id="main_search">
                    <div class="form-group row search_repeated search_group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2 word_repeated">
                            <label style="font-size: large; padding-top: 5px">Sentence or Word</label>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Filter -->
                        <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2">
                            <select name="formsets_option" id="formsets_option" class="form-control">
                                {% if formsets_option == 'contains' %}
                                <option id="contains" value="contains" selected>contains</option>
                                {% else %}
                                <option id="contains" value="contains">contains</option>
                                {% endif %}
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-4 d-inline p-2">
                            <input id="search_btn" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   onkeyup="if (this.value != ''){document.getElementById('clear').hidden=false} else {document.getElementById('clear').hidden=true}"
                                   placeholder="search" name="query" value="{{ request.GET.query }}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2">
                            <select name="verb_option" id="verb_option" class="form-control">
                                {% if verb_option == '' %}
                                <option value="" selected>Any POS</option>
                                {% else %}
                                <option value="">Any POS</option>
                                {% endif %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div style="align-self: center;font-size: 14px;color: #2f855a;" class="btn-plus col-lg-1 d-inline">
                            <div class="fa fa-plus d-inline"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input type="submit" name="main_search" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <a href="{% url 'search:search' %}" style="color: #c53030; margin-left: 10px;border: 0; background-color: transparent;cursor: pointer" id="clear" hidden>Clear Search</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                {% else %}
                    <form method="get" id="main_search">
                        {% for q, formsets_option, verb_option in multiple_requests %}
                        <div class="form-group row search_repeated search_group">
                            <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2 word_repeated">
                                <label style="font-size: large; padding-top: 5px">Sentence or Word</label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Filter -->
                            <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2">
                                <select name="formsets_option" id="formsets_option" class="form-control">
                                    {% if formsets_option == 'contains' %}
                                    <option id="contains" value="contains" selected>contains</option>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <option id="contains" value="contains">contains</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 d-inline p-2">
                                <input id="search_btn" type="text" class="form-control"
                                       onkeyup="if (this.value != ''){document.getElementById('clear').hidden=false} else {document.getElementById('clear').hidden=true}"
                                       placeholder="search" name="query" value="{{ q }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 d-inline p-2">
                                <select name="verb_option" id="verb_option" class="form-control">
                                    {% if verb_option == '' %}
                                    <option value="" selected>Any POS</option>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <option value="">Any POS</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div style="align-self: center;font-size: 14px;color: #2f855a;" class="btn-plus col-lg-1 d-inline">
                                <div class="fa fa-plus d-inline"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <div class="out_search_group">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" name="main_search" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <a href="{% url 'search:search' %}" style="color: #c53030; margin-left: 10px;border: 0; background-color: transparent;cursor: pointer" id="clear" hidden>Clear Search</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
```

search.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        let search_group = $(".search_group")
        let out_search_group = $(".out_search_group")

        let create_times_parent = document.createElement("div")
        create_times_parent.classList.add("btn-times", "col-lg-1", "d-inline")
        let create_times = document.createElement("div")
        //added on extra class here..
        create_times.classList.add("fa", "fa-times", "d-inline", "remove")
        create_times_parent.appendChild(create_times)

        // field number just one field
        if (search_group.length < 2 && search_group.length > 0)
        {
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-plus', function ()
            {
                $("div.search_group:first-of-type").after(search_group.clone(true, true));
                search_group.addClass('created')
                search_group.append(create_times_parent)
            });

            //onclick of remove..
            $(document).on("click", ".remove", function ()
            {
                $(this).closest('.created').remove() //get closest outer div
                console.log("clicked")
            })
        // field number more than one field
        } else
            {
            search_group.not(":first").append(create_times_parent)

            $(document).on('click', '.btn-plus', function ()
            {
                let search_cloned = $(this).parent('.search_repeated').clone(true, true);
                $("div.out_search_group").append(search_cloned);
                console.log("has cloned")
                console.log(search_cloned)
                search_cloned.addClass('created')
                console.log("has class created")
                console.log(search_cloned)
                search_cloned.append(create_times_parent)
                console.log("has times shape")
                console.log(search_cloned)
            });

            //onclick of remove..
            $(document).on("click", ".remove", function ()
            {
                $(this).closest('.created').remove() //get closest outer div
                $(this).parent('.btn-times').parent('.search_repeated').remove()
                console.log("clicked")
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

views.py

I return this to make the condition that tells me if query length more than one or not

```
context = {'query_length': request.GET.getlist('query')}
```

Comment: Hi, is this issue resolved ?

Comment: yes, it is do you need any help?